# postgresql : passing values object with matching column fields to insert command

Tags: postgresql

If I have a car object

```
let car = {
 'model': Audi,
 'price' : 3000
}
```

DO I have to be explicit with specifying all the values like this : ('Audi,3000) ?

Can I not do ?:

```
insert into cars_table values (car);
```

Comment: In postgres a column may have a default value, usually NULL but you can set it to whatever you like which will be inserted if you don't explicitly specify a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to map application objects to database rows by using an ORM, which stands for Object Relation Mapping.

When using an ORM you will first need to teach it what is your schema, which will create an object throw where you can access data in the database.

A popular ORM for JavaScript is [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/)

example:

```
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Car extends Model {}
Car.init({
   model: DataTypes.STRING,
   price: DataTypes.NUMBER
}, { modelName: 'car' });

(async () => {
    await sequelize.sync();
    const car = await Car.create({
       model: 'Audi',
       price: 1000000
    });
    console.log(car.toJSON());
})();
```

See the docs in the link above for additional information.

There are ORMs for all programming languages.